# babel-jest ES2015 import statements

Tags: node.js, babeljs, jestjs

has anyone been writing jasmine / jest tests using es2015 syntax? how much shimming / polyfill / gerrymandering does it require?

i’m having trouble importing functions correctly. i have one module:
**…./utils/TweetUtils.js**

```
'use strict';

export function getListOfTweetIds (tweets) {
  return Object.keys(tweets);
};
```

and one test suite:

**…./__tests__/TweetUtils-test.js**

```
'use strict';
jest.dontMock('../TweetUtils');
import * as TweetUtils from '../TweetUtils';

describe('Tweet utilities module', () => {

  it('has access to the TweetUtils methods', () => {

    let testObj = {a:'a',b:'b',c:'c'};
    // Passes
    expect(TweetUtils.getListOfTweetIds).toBeDefined();
    // Passes
    expect(typeof TweetUtils.getListOfTweetIds).toBe('function');
    // Fails
    expect(TweetUtils.getListOfTweetIds(testObj)).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

If I hack a console output into the suite with something like this:`expect(‘’).toBe(TweetUtils);`

Jasmine reports this:

```
- Expected: '' toBe: {
      default: {
          getListOfTweetIds: Function
      },
      getListOfTweetIds: Function
  }
```

So it seems like the import statement is doing something, but it’s clearly not importing my methods honestly. I get the same results when I import using the named function syntax: `import {getListOfTweetIds} from ‘../TweetUtils’;`
But if I use the default syntax: `import getListOfTweetIds from ‘../TweetUtils’;`
The second spec fails - it’s no longer `typeof function`, but `typeof object // => {default: Function}`

I’ve been combing the docs and open-issues. There’ve been related issues for a few months, but the known issues don’t seem right. I’ve tried importing my jest.dontMock statements to avoid hoisting, circa: https://github.com/babel/babel-jest/issues/16 but no dice.

Everything works if I modify **TweetUtils.js** to use `module.exports = function…` and bring it into the suite using `const myFunction = require(‘../TweetUtils’)`, but it doesn’t feel like I’m channeling the true ES2015 magic. Is everyone just dealing with wonky work-arounds right now while the ecosystem catches up to the new syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, `import` statements are hoisted and it causes problems with the jest auto-mocking feature (the module is imported **before** you tell jest to unmocked it).

`TweetUtils.getListOfTweetIds` is correctly imported but it's mocked, so each calls return `undefined`. That's why the third expectation fails.

Importing `jest.dontMock` statement could work (I tested it) but it sounds dirty to me (do you really want to create a "dontmock module" file for each test modules ?)

You have to use the `require` syntax for the tested module. Replace

```
import * as TweetUtils from '../TweetUtils';
```

by

```
const TweetUtils = require('../TweetUtils');
```

It was the same in jest example before I fixed it : [jest#379](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/379)

Comment: In my case this only worked when I added .default: `const TweetUtils = require('../TweetUtils').default;`

Answer (score -1):

The issue seems to be with babel and not with jest . Try this solution.

> #### If you are using 'create-react-app' then install these dev dependencies:

```
"babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
"babel-jest": "^22.4.1",
"babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.1",
```

And also update the `.babelrc` (create this file if it doesn't exist ) :

```
{
"presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
      ]
}
```

And now both jest and npm test both work as they should.