# Jest React testing es6 import/export unwanted mock

Tags: javascript, testing, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs

When using the ES6 import/export syntax it seems that Jest is autoMocking the components I import by default even though I explicitly turn mocking off for the component.

```
jest.autoMockOff();
jest.dontMock("../bundles/Opportunities/MarkAsLost.jsx");
```

this is the import at the top of the test component:

```
import MarkAsLost from "../bundles/Opportunities/MarkAsLost.jsx";
```

this is the export at the bottom of the component being tested:

```
export default MarkAsLost;
```

this is the result of logging the imported component in the test file:

```
{ [Function]
  _isMockFunction: true,
  _getMockImplementation: [Function],
  mock: { calls: [ [Object] ], instances: [ [Object] ] },
  mockClear: [Function],
  mockReturnValueOnce: [Function],
  mockReturnValue: [Function],
  mockImpl: [Function],
  mockImplementation: [Function],
  mockReturnThis: [Function],
  displayName: 'MarkAsLost' }
```

when I use the old style syntax i.e:

```
var MarkAsLost = require("../bundles/Opportunities/MarkAsLost.jsx");
module.exports = MarkAsLost;
```

this is the result of loggin the component which now behaves as I want in the test file

```
{ [Function] displayName: 'MarkAsLost' }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If it's an option, I might recommend checking out [Enzyme](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/). You might have a much happier unit-testing experience. :)

Comment: Enzyme is awesome. But @ffxsam your comment is out of context here.

Comment: Sure. Which is why I just made it a comment as opposed to an answer.

Comment: related/ dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882868/babel-jest-es2015-

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue, `jest.*` methods didn't work at all, moving "unmocking" feature to [Jest's configuration](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#unmockedmodulepathpatterns-array-string) in package.json on the other hand - worked correctly:

```
{
  "jest": {
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      ".*"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. Jest was mocking axios and because of that one of the dependencies wasn’t instantiating in tests. So I just added `jest.unmock(axios)` a the top of the test file.